# reloadAllTimelines not working with UserDefaults

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit

My Widget loads some data from `UserDefaults/ Appgroups` and depending on that it shows some text and a picture.
This works with the first start.
If I change the UserDefaults and use `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()` it only changes the picture not the text.

What can I do? Are there other options to share data between main app and widget? Seems to be a bug.

This is my Widgetentry:

```
struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    
    let networkManager = NetworkManager()
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: ConfigurationIntent(), clubnamehome: "test", clubnameaway: "test2")
    }
    
   func getSnapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        networkManager.fetchData { (post) in
      let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: configuration, clubnamehome: post.home_name, clubnameaway: post.away_name)
                completion(entry)
            
        }
        
        
    }
    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        networkManager.fetchData { (post) in
 let entries = [ SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: configuration, clubnamehome: post.home_name, clubnameaway: post.away_name) ]
                 let reloadTime = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 5, to: Date())!
                let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .after(reloadTime))
                completion(timeline)
        }
    }
   
}
```

Here I set the value for UserDefault:

```
@IBAction func losGehts(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        switch team {
        case "arminia":
 UserDefaults(suiteName: "...")!.set("114", forKey: "tabellenId")
            
            
            if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
            
        case "augsburg":
```

And this my view:

```
struct MyTeamWidgetEntryView : View {
    
    
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    var imageIcon = "stuttgart"
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    let logo = UserDefaults(suiteName: "...")!.string(forKey: "logo")
    let mannschaftsName = UserDefaults(suiteName: "...")!.string(forKey: "teamname")
    let teamID = "289"
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                Spacer().frame(height: 10)
                
                // image von hier
                
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    switch logo {
                    case "arminia":
                        Image("bundesliga1/arminia").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit).frame(width: 25, height: 25, alignment: .bottomLeading)
                    case "augsburg":
                        Image("bundesliga1/augsburg").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit).frame(width: 25, height: 25, alignment: .bottomLeading)
                   
                    default:
                        Image("bundesliga1/...").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit).frame(width: 90, height: 90, alignment: .center)
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                // image bis hier
                Spacer().frame(height: 5)
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 6) {
                
                VStack {
                    HStack{
                        Text(entry.clubnamehome).font(.system(size: 10)).bold()
                        Text(":").font(.system(size: 10)).bold()
                        Text(entry.clubnameaway).font(.system(size: 10)).bold()
                        Spacer()
                        //überlegen ob spacer rein soll oder nicht
                        
                    }
                    
                   
                    
                }
            }
            
            
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you correctly read `logo` and `mannschaftsName` values from App Group UserDefaults:

```
struct MyTeamWidgetEntryView : View {
    let logo = UserDefaults(suiteName: "...")!.string(forKey: "logo")
    let mannschaftsName = UserDefaults(suiteName: "...")!.string(forKey: "teamname")
```

Now you need to make sure you set these values correctly in your main App. In the code you posted you set a value for the `tabellenId` key only:

```
case "arminia":
    UserDefaults(suiteName: "...")!.set("114", forKey: "tabellenId")
```

You need to update `logo` and `mannschaftsName` as well:

```
case "arminia":
    UserDefaults(suiteName: "...")!.set("114", forKey: "tabellenId")
    UserDefaults(suiteName: "...")!.set("???", forKey: "logo")
    UserDefaults(suiteName: "...")!.set("???", forKey: "mannschaftsName")
```

This may be extracted, so you *don't repeat yourself*:

```
switch team {
    ...
}

UserDefaults(suiteName: "...")!.set(team, forKey: "mannschaftsName")
```

Answer (score 0):

2022年12月11日 08:33:36 Resoled

- 1.Use `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()`
- 2.Use `UserDefaults(suiteName: "...")!.string(forKey: "xxx")` **only work in your View, not Widget or WidgetBundle.**
- 3.Done(After reload in you app foreground, WidgetKit reload instantly.)

**BTW: `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadTimelines(ofKind: "YourKind")` is also
work fine.**